# Find the domain of $g(t)=\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{t}}$

Tags: functions, problem-solving

$$g(t) = \sqrt{\frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{t}}$$

Case 1: $t/2 - 1/t \geq  0$ ; $t \geq 2$

Case 2: $t$ cannot equal $0$

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: You mean $\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{t}}$.

Comment: How do I format it like that? I've done it before but I didn't seem to have the option this time

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want 2 criteria, but they are not independent cases:

1. $t\ne 0$
2. $t/2 - 1/t \ge 0 \iff t/2 \ge 1/t$

In the second case, it will help to distinguish between $t>0$ and $t<0$. Can you finish it?

Comment: t^2 >= 2 ------> t >= sqrt(2) So case 1 becomes irrelevant?

Comment: @JoshWhite There are no cases. $t\ne 0$ is a necessary condition in the 2nd case as well. Also note that the second case implies $t^2\ge 1/2$ only if $t>0$, but if $t<0$, it's a different story.

Comment: Then the domain is [sqrt(2), infinity) ?